# (Python) Flask - request.args.get returning NoneType

Tags: python, flask, request

All I need to complete this website is for it to grab the `n` and `s` values from the input.
But when executing `request.get.args` is returning None everytime
Here's the code:

`my_website.py`:

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask,render_template, url_for, redirect, request


app = Flask(__name__)
conn = sqlite3.connect('shoes.db', check_same_thread=False)
c = conn.cursor()

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def main():

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('main.html')

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect(url_for('search'))


@app.route("/search/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def search():

    if not request.args.get("n"):           
        raise RuntimeError("missing n")

    if not request.args.get("s"):
        raise RuntimeError("missing s")

    name = request.args.get('n')
    size = request.args.get('s')
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM shoes WHERE name LIKE ? AND sizes LIKE ? ORDER BY price",
                    ('%'+name+'%','%'+size+'%'))

    p = c.fetchall()

    url = [p[i][0] for i in range(len(p))]
    names = [p[i][1] for i in range(len(p))]
    prices = [p[i][2] for i in range(len(p))]
    sizes = [p[i][3] for i in range(len(p))]
    shoe_type = [p[i][4] for i in range(len(p))]

    return render_template('search.html' , url=url, names=names, prices=prices,
                           sizes=sizes, shoe_type=shoe_type)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`main.html`:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

<form action = "{{ url_for('main') }}" class="form" method = "POST" >
    <div>
        <h1>Soccer Shoes Finder</h1>
        <div class="line-separator"></div>
        <div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <input name = "n" type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
                <input name = "s" type="text" placeholder="Size"/>
                <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
RuntimeError: missing n
```

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`request.args` holds the values in the *query string*. Your form on the other hand is sending values in the POST body.

Use the [`request.form` mapping](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.form) instead, or use [`request.values`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.values), which combines `request.form` and `request.args`.

Alternatively, change your form `method` to `GET` to have the browser put the arguments in the query string instead.

Comment: Also, wouldn't I'll have to change the `{{ url_for('main') }}` to `{{ url_for('search') }}` if i'm using `request.form` to get those values? Don't know if what I'm saying makes sense.

Comment: @tadm123: yes, you want to post directly to `search`, not redirect  from `main` as POST data doesn't survive a redirect.

Comment: Hmm the problem is that I'm using POST for when the user clicks the button on `main.html`, so that when he completes the form it redirects to the `search.html` template and displays all the information. so i need the POST to be on `{{ url_for('main') }}`.

Comment: Thanks for `request.values` I didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

This is a ***really*** bad idea.

```
if not request.args.get("n"):           
        raise RuntimeError("missing n")

    if not request.args.get("s"):
        raise RuntimeError("missing n")
```

First of all, using the `.get()` function will return `None` if the value isn't set, in turn not giving an index error like getting a list index would.

If you are hell bent on returning an error, you're better of giving a `ValueError`.

Otherwise, I'd be doing (and probably should anyway) client side form validation with javascript, it could just be making sure that the inputs aren't empty with a required attribute.

Also, try naming your `name=""` more accurately, instead of using `n` for name, actually use `name`, it just makes everything far easier to understand developing it.

Comment: if you want errors to be thrown just call request.args("n") without the .get() according to flask documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

> ***request.get_data()***

It returns dictionary object.