# Why is args.get() returning None in Python?

Tags: python, rest, flask

I am trying to get a query parameter by the name of 'indicator_id' but for some reason it is always of type None, as returned by args.get()

```
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('indicator_id', type = str, required=True)

@api.route('/collections?indicator_id=<indicator_id>', methods = ['GET', 'DELETE'])
@api.expect(parser)
class Collection(Resource):

    @api.response(201, 'Created Successfully')
    @api.response(404, 'Indicator not found')
    def get (self, indicator_id):

        args = parser.parse_args()
        indicator_id = args.get('indicator_id')
        print(str(indicator_id))
```

Comment: have you passed indicator_id as an argument?

Comment: where do I need to pass it as an argument?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Python) Flask - request.args.get returning NoneType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42687067/python-flask-request-args-get-returning-nonetype)

Comment: No, I have already seen this article, it does not answer my question. I am using flask rest plus

Comment: in your get request are you passing indicator_id, something like ..../collections/?indicator_id or either in your CuRL request?

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but now I am getting a 404 error not found "The requested URL was not found on the server"

Comment: Can you share the url you tried while getting 404 @Adam

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to describe your query params in api.route, just retrieve them in view-function as request.args or dict(request.args) as u want.

If you want that it be a part of url u need to describe it as dynamic path:

```
@app.route('/path/<path:subpath>')
def show_subpath(subpath):
    pass
```